# remove folder from url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have a folder named pages which includes the pages for my site, when opening one of these files the url reads -

**zebrafishweb/pages/contact**

I would like it to just read

**zebrafishweb/contact**

I already have this htaccess file to remove any .php .html extensions which i would also like to carry on using. I don't have a clue how to write these htaccess files just copied it from the web and tailored it to me!

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule ^(themes|order-now|submissions|faq|contact)$ $1.php [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^(home|faq)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You already have a .htaccess inside `/pages/` subdirectory with some rules for `.php` and `.html` extensions
2. You want a redirect to shorter URI `/contact` instead of `/pages/contact`

With those you can have your rules like this:

site root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^contact/?$ pages/contact.php [L,NC]
```

`pages/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to shorter URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pages(/contact)[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=302]

# add .php to these files
RewriteRule ^(themes|order-now|submissions|faq|contact)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

# add .html to these files
RewriteRule ^(home|faq)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you sir for sharing nice answer. Just want to check here by `site root .htaccess` you mean htaccess(new one) should be along side with pages folder? Thank you.

Comment: Yes site root directory should be one level above pages directory